# #Error in a greater than iif sum statement

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I'm trying to write some code that will prevent a #Error.

I don't know where my issue is.

```
=Sum(IIF(Fields!CurrentNumDaysOD.Value >= 1 And Fields!CurrentNumDaysOD.Value <= 10,
Fields!CurrentBalance.Value, "0")) / Sum(IIF(Fields!CurrentNumDaysOD.Value > 0, 
Fields!CurrentBalance.Value, "0"))
```

I have also attempted this:

```
=Sum(IIF(Fields!CurrentNumDaysOD.Value >= 1 And Fields!CurrentNumDaysOD.Value <= 10,
 Fields!CurrentBalance.Value, Nothing)) / Sum(IIF(Fields!CurrentNumDaysOD.Value > 0,
 Fields!CurrentBalance.Value, Nothing))
```

Answer (score 0):

If the result of the second half of your statement (after the `/`) is 0, then you will be dividing by 0, which will cause an error.

Comment: I understand that actually.  I have tried several variations and nothing has worked

Comment: Is this in a spreadsheet cell, or in a macro?  It looks like it's in a spreadsheet cell, in which case you should be using `IF`, not `IIF`.

Comment: This is actually in SSRS